# verify react functional component to be there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I'm new to react unit testing, here I have react code which works fine but need to unit test it.
I want to verify the component to be there, I have tried in two different ways and both of them does not work:
I'm using `useSelector` and `useDispatch` thats why `connect(null,null)`.

my code:

M2SelectionCard.js:

```
function ConnectedSelectionCard({ classes }) {
  

  return (
    <Card data-testid="M2SelectionCardd" className={classes.selectionCard}>
      <CardContent>
        
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}

const M2SelectionCard = connect(null, null)(ConnectedSelectionCard);

export default M2SelectionCard;
```

first I did like this:

```
import React from "react";

import { expect } from "@jest/globals";
import { render, screen, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import M2SelectionCard from "../M2SelectionCard";

test("test", () => {
  render(<M2SelectionCard />);
  const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("M2SelectionCardd");
  expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  // expect(true).toBe(true);
});
```

and got error : `Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ConnectedSelectionCard)"`. Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or pass a custom React context provider to `<Provider>` and the corresponding React context consumer to `Connect(ConnectedSelectionCard)` in connect options.'

```
import React from "react";
import { expect } from "@jest/globals";
import { render, screen, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import M2SelectionCard from "../M2SelectionCard";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../../redux/store";

const store = configureStore({});

it("test", () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <M2SelectionCard />
    </Provider>
  );
  const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("M2SelectionCardd");
  expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

after that I added store to it in test (don't know should I add it here ?):
error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionCard' of undefined`
it points to `className={classes.selectionCard}`
any idea ?

Comment: You need to also pass a `classes` prop. An empty object shall suffice so there's a defined object to reference into. Why are you connecting `ConnectedSelectionCard` to your redux store if you neither access any state nor dispatch any actions?

Comment: what is the point of `const M2SelectionCard = connect(null, null)(ConnectedSelectionCard);` if you aren't actually connecting this element to redux?

Comment: I'm using useSelector and useDispatch so i am connecting to redux... i dont need that connect ? i just converted class to functional hooks

Comment: If you are using the react-redux hooks to connect to a redux context then no, you don't need the `connect` Higher Order Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectionCard' of undefined'`
>
> pointing to `className={classes.selectionCard}`

This error is saying that it cannot access a `selectionCard` property of an undefined object, `classes` in this case.

Given component under test:

```
function ConnectedSelectionCard({ classes }) {
  ...

  return (
    <Card data-testid="M2SelectionCardd" className={classes.selectionCard}>
      <CardContent>
        
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

You should still pass all the expected props, i.e. a `classes` prop. For this purpose an empty object is sufficient enough to access into. In other words, if `classes` is an empty object then `classes.selectionCard` evaluates to `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

```
it("test", () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <M2SelectionCard classes={{}} /> // <-- pass a classes prop
    </Provider>
  );
  const SelectionCardElement = screen.getByTestId("M2SelectionCardd");
  expect(SelectionCardElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: now its working, you gave good explanation ! if i'm going to read this test, would it be like : component is verified to be there ? and could you possibly add some button and onclick to verify that button is clicked, cuz in other examples they use 'shallow' which comes from 'enzyme'

Comment: @walee Well, the `getBy*` query not throwing an error is sufficient enough to know the element/component was mounted and found, no assertion necessary. See [types of queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries), `getBy*` queries throw an error if 0 or more than 1 match is found. Yes, you can use React-Testing-Library to interact with your UI and test it. When using RTL I wouldn't draw many direct comparisons to Enzyme as these are two relatively orthogonal testing paradigms.

Comment: i have another question related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69123963/verify-state-to-have-changed-from-false-to-true-when-clicked